# Using ContentPartRecord causes runtime error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, nhibernate, orchardcms

I am trying to add a widget to an Orchard site and I made a new content part that inherits from ContentPartRecord. It builds just fine but when I go to run Orchard.exe or when I browse to the site I get this error:

```
Exception Details: NHibernate.MappingException: Association references unmapped class: System.string
```

Here is my class:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using Orchard.ContentManagement;
using Orchard.ContentManagement.Records;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Hjn.Models
{
public class PropertySearchRecord : ContentPartRecord
{
    public virtual List<string> PropertyTypes { get; set; }
    public virtual List<string> Locations { get; set; }
    public virtual List<double> MinimumPrices { get; set; }
    public virtual List<double> MaximumPrices { get; set; }
}

public class PropertySearchPart : ContentPart<PropertySearchRecord>
{
    [Required]
    public List<string> PropertyTypes
    {
        get { return Record.PropertyTypes; }
        set { Record.PropertyTypes = value; }
    }

    [Required]
    public List<string> Locations
    {
        get { return Record.Locations; }
        set { Record.Locations = value; }
    }

    [Required]
    public List<double> MinimumPrices
    {
        get { return Record.MinimumPrices; }
        set { Record.MinimumPrices = value; }

    }

    [Required]
    public List<double> MaximumPrices
    {
        get { return Record.MaximumPrices; }
        set { Record.MaximumPrices = value; }
    }
}
}
```

I'm pretty lost with this one.
I can post the stack trace too if you'd like. Just let me know. Thanks!

Comment: Seems like it's those list columns that are confusing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, don't use List<> types for your columns. Instead, manage them as n-n relationships. There is a doc topic on that: http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Creating-1-n-and-n-n-relations